# Return an array from let using doseq and into

Tags: clojure

I am trying to return a list from a let statement.

```
(let [data []]
 (doseq [x ["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"]]
  (into data (do-stuff x))) data)
```

However the `data` list is always empty.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185522/clojure-let-scope-and-function-return-value) answer on returning values from the let scope however could not fix this.

Comment: `data` is immutable - if you want to return `["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"]` you can just return it directly instead of trying to copy it to a new list.

Comment: this was just an example,the `["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"]` is a varible which could be any list

Comment: Right, but whatever the list is you can just return directly since it is immutable.

Comment: Edited the question,I need to perform a funciton on x too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to understand the looping mechanism in Clojure, you are probably looking for this (assuming that what you are doing is just an exercise in how collections work):

`(for [x ["1" "2" "3"]] x)`

The result is:

`("1" "2" "3")`

Of course, if this is all you are going to do, you already have the collection and don't need to build it.

Based on your edit, do this:

`(for [x ["1" "2" "3"]] (do-stuff x))`

There are many other ways to do this type of stuff though, like using `map` or `reduce` and other tools, depending on the complexity of `do-stuff` and what it needs access to.

Remember, values in Clojure are immutable be default. You cannot mutate your `data` at all, it is fixed at a value of `[]`. Unless you make it an `atom`, which is unnecessary for what you need. Functional programming is about building values, not mutating variables.

There are many ways to express what you are trying to do, but `for` is the list-building ("list comprehension") version of `do-seq` as they share the same general structure. Since your question was about `do-seq`, I discuss `for` for good measure. But `map` is a better choice here. If you really *need* it to be a vector as opposed to a lazy sequence, then use `mapv`.

If you needed something called `data` that holds these results, then just do this:

```
(let [data (for [x ["1" "2" "3"]] x)] ;;or map, etc
   ;;do something with data
 )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to modify each element and return a vector you can use `mapv`:

```
(mapv do-stuff ["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"])
```

or you can use `map` if you just need a sequence output:

```
(map do-stuff ["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"])
```

or a for expression:

```
(for [x ["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"]] (do-stuff x))
```

`for` expressions return a sequence which you can convert into a vector using `vec` if required:

```
(vec (for [x ["0" "1" "2" "3" "4"]] (do-stuff x)))
```